# Code rewritten after some clues gathered from community (logic still does not work)

Tags: mysql

I have made some changes to my code from previous version in which inner if statement always evaluated to false. Logic still does not work. Now it always evaluates to true even when wrong user and/or password are entered. It is rather simple code, I do not get why this is failing:

```
    <?php

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customerdirectory");

        if($conn->connect_error)
        {
            echo("Connection Failed " . $conn->connect_error);
            exit();
        }


        if(isset($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"])) 
        {      
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["user"]);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["pass"]); 

            $result = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name='$username' AND password='$password'";

            if($conn->query($result))
                echo("Succesful Login: Welcome".$username);
            else
                echo("User and/or password are not correct!!");
};
         $conn->close();
     ?>
```

Comment: Which part is always evaluating as true? And what values do those variables contain?

Comment: This part always evaluates to true:

Comment: Your comment was truncated, comments don't allow multi-line entries.

Comment: This part always evaluates to true:

Comment: if($conn->query($result))
                echo("Succesful Login: Welcome".$username);
            else
                echo("User and/or password are not correct!!");
};

Comment: This part always evaluates to true: if($conn->query($result)) echo("Succesful Login: Welcome".$username); else echo("User and/or password are not correct!!"); };. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I don't recommend authorizing a user this way. I would instead recommend getting the password and doing the comparison in code. I say that because you are relying on SQL to tell you if this person is authorized, but the only thing you get back is a record if the match is correct. What if something is wrong and you get back a record anyway? How do you know they are really authorized?

Comment: Please verify the result which is returned and I believe you will find some value you did not expect being returned within your result.

Comment: Customerdirectory is my database, customer is a table and name and password are fields within.

Comment: No, I mean the result from your query "$conn->query($result)", it's returning a match if there is a result (matching user and pass). But have you verified the result you received matched what you expected and that no other unexpected data is unintentionally being returned instead.

Comment: I finally got it working using this code inside instead: $sql = "SELECT * from customer WHERE name = '$username' AND password = '$password'"; 

        
        if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
         $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
         if($rowcount == 1)
          echo("Login Successful");
         else
          echo("Login Unsuccessful");
         mysqli_free_result($result);
        };